# Como evitar logout do usuário ao fechar o navegador com PHP?

Tags: php, session

Eu atualmente uso `SESSION`. Quando fecho o navegador, ele desconecta. Como posso fazer um jeito no login de ao clicar em continuar conectado, o usuário não desconectar após fechar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toda sessão é um cookie, mas os dados do cookie ficam salvos no servidor ao invés do navegador, o cookie de uma sessão é como se fosse um *token*

Você pode usar o [**`session_set_cookie_params`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

```
void session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] )
```

Setando o `lifetime` irá aumentar o tempo da sessão, pois tecnicamente é impossível criar uma sessão infinita.

O que ficaria assim:

```
session_set_cookie_params(<tempo em segundos>);
session_start();
```

No entanto ele não atualiza depois de criado o Cookie, então talvez tenha que usar `setcookie`:

```
session_set_cookie_params(<tempo de vida>);
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + <tempo de vida>, '/');
```

Você também pode implementar um Ajax simples para ficar rodando um script pequeno, somente para manter a sessão:

**sessao.php**

```
<?php

$tempodevida = 2678400; // 1 ano de vida
session_set_cookie_params($tempodevida);
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + $tempodevida, '/');
```

Ajax com JavaScript:

```
(function sessao() {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", "sessao.php", true);
    oReq.onload = function () {
        //Após o Ajax terminar a requisição executará daqui 5 segundos
        setTimeout(sessao, 5000);
    };
    oReq.send(null);
})();//Auto executa
```

Com jQuery:

```
(function sessao() {
    $.ajax("sessao.php").then(function () {
        //Após o Ajax terminar a requisição executará daqui 5 segundos
        setTimeout(sessao, 5000);
    });
})();//Auto executa
```

No entanto preciso deixar claro que isto não irá afetar o `session.gc_maxlifetime`, pois isto é resolvido no back-end pelo proprio PHP, você pode até tentar estender o tempo mudando o php.ini esta linha:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=coloque aqui o tempo limite;
```

Ainda sim isso irá afetar todas sessões, o que nem sempre será o que deseja.

---

### Como o navegador interpreta com session_set_cookie_params e sem

Sem definir `session_set_cookie_params`:

[image: sem session_set_cookie_params]

Com `session_set_cookie_params`:

[image: com session_set_cookie_params]

Ou seja, quando *Expires/Max-age* for igual a `Session` significa que quando o navegador for fechado e abrir novamente esse cookie deixará de existir, mas quando definido o tempo de vida o cookie passa a ter uma data para expirar e toda vez que usar sessão o tempo será atualizado.

Comment: Isso irá funcionar mesmo se o cara fechar o navegador?

Comment: @lffg atualizei a resposta, pode experimentar, se algo falha me avisa.

Answer (score 1):

Colocando um cookie. Nesses casos eu coloco o cookie com um valor qualquer (geralmente uso uniqid) e salvo no banco de dados com o IP do cara, assim não corro o risco. Toda vez que ele abrir eu verifico se o cookie existe e busco no banco de dados o cookie para conferir o IP atual com o IP que está no banco de dados.

Comment: Olá, pode explicar melhor como funciona?